# Explanation for this Counting COUNT behaviour

Tags: mysql

I'm having problems understanding this behaviour, can someone explain this to me ? What I want to retrieve is all parent users ids but without the parent whom his children has leave the school **escolarity.baja = 1**. In this table "escolarity" the field "baja" could be '', NULL, 0 or 1. THE EMBEDDED select part like this "esc.baja != 1" means user has not leave school but this does not exclude 1 values in field "baja" however if I set "esc.baja != 0" it count only the baja=1 and return field only when esc.baja=1 .
why this happens?

```
    SELECT user.id
    FROM usuario as user 
    JOIN user_type as ut ON (ut.tipo=4 AND ut.id_usuario=user.id    ) 
    JOIN alumno_parent as prog ON prog.id_parent = user.id
    JOIN escolarity as esc ON prog.id_alumno = esc.id_alumno 
    WHERE 1 AND 
    # EMBEDDED select
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM alumno_parent as ap 
         JOIN user_type as ut1 ON (ut1.id_usuario=ap.id_alumno AND ut1.tipo = 1 ) 
         JOIN matric as mat ON (mat.id_alumno = ut1.id_usuario AND id_grupo = 464)
         JOIN escolarity as esc ON mat.id_alumno = esc.id_alumno   
         WHERE ap.id_parent = user.id AND esc.baja != 1 ) > 0 
    GROUP BY user.id ORDER BY user.apellido1, user.apellido2 , user.nombre;
```

Comment: I think sample data and desired results would really help others understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Don't use the same aliases for tables in the same query/subquery (it is confusing and easy to make a mistake) - See `esc`. Furthermore keep in mind that `esc.baja != 1` will exclude all records with NULL in the field baja, essentially saying `esc.baja = 0` when you have only 0, 1 and NULL in the column - this is true the other way around, saying `esc.baja != 0` means `esc.baja = 1` and excludes NULLs. Always(!) handle NULLs, or at least think about it.